# Why we use environments under pipelines in Azure Devops? and is there any Monthly/Yearly limitation in creating builds / releases?

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-server-2019, devops-services

First i need to know why we use environments under pipelines in Azure devops
and Is there any Monthly/Yearly limitation in creating build or releases in Azure DevOps?
Anyone Please HELP !

Comment: Did you read the documentation on that feature?

Comment: @DanielMann yeah i read that. it mentions about the build time limit. But i need to know that whether there exist any limit on the number of builds that can be made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a doc about [the advantages of using environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops).

> 1.Deployment history
>
> 2.Traceability of commits and work items
>
> 3.Diagnose resource health
>
> 4.Permissions

> whether there exist any limit on the number of builds that can be made

There is no limit. You can create hundreds or even thousands of pipelines for no charge. You can register any number of self-hosted agents for no charge.

But as you said, they have build time limit and parallel job limit.

You could refer [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops#microsoft-hosted-cicd) for more detailed information.